# Актуально сейчас?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, плеоназм

Можно ли, согласно речевым нормам языка, со словом *(не)актуально* употреблять слово *сейчас*?

Answer (score 3):

> [АКТУАЛЬНЫЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. [лат. actualis действительный, настоящий]. Важный, существенный для решения проблем, задач настоящего времени; насущный, злободневный, современный. А. вопрос. А-ая задача, тема, проблема. Исследование, а-ое для экологии. Шекспировские пьесы актуальны и сегодня. <Актуально, нареч. Актуальность, -и; ж.

Думаю, Вы заподозрили, что тут есть плеоназм (в определении слова *актуально* уже заложено настоящее время, то есть сейчас). Возможно, Вы и правы, но на практике выражение "актуально сейчас" встречается часто. Заметьте, слово "актуально" употребляется также по отношению к прошлому и будущему (*было актуально в свое время*, *станет актуальным в следующем году*), поэтому я бы сказал, что употребление выражения "актуально сейчас" оправдано, когда есть прямое или скрытое противопоставление актуальности в другое время (*Шекспировские пьесы актуальны и сегодня/сейчас*).